# MongoDB unique index allows duplication

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new in mongoDb and I have a problem with mongock. Previously I had an index defined by annotation like below. In my unit test I have a case which tries to save same value on the same field and it throws exception as expected.

```
@Indexed(unique = true)
private String name;
```

I removed @Indexed annotation and I created index by mongock migration. But in this time I am able to insert a record with same value for this column without getting exception. So what is wrong here and why it is not working as it works above. I created my migration as :

```
collection.createIndex(
                    new Document(new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
                            .put("name", 1)
                            .build()),
                    new IndexOptions().name("name_idx").unique(true),
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

Without providing information about the version you are using, it's hard to say.

However I believe your issue can be related to an old existing bug.

Please use the last version 4.0.8.alpha, which is alpha as features are still being added, but very stable(there is no official documentation yet, but you can see the [sample project](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock-integration-tests/tree/master/mongock-spring-v5/mongock-spring5-springdata3-it) here) or the last official stable version: 3.3.2.

Please notice that in both case you should use MongockTemplate, instead of MongoTemplate.

I believe that will solve your issue. Otherwise, please provide version and stack trace.